# How to use scala list and java list in the same file in scala code base?

Tags: java, scala

I have a use case where I want to use scala list and java list in the same file in scala codebase. I am using java list by importing java.util.list. Now If I want to use the scala list in the same file, it's taking that list as java list and throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Fully Qualified Name (FQN)

- Java `List` is `java.utils.List`
- Scala `List` is `scala.collection.immutable.List`

You also use alias:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.{List=>ScalaList}
import java.utils.{List=>JavaList}
```

Now you can refer to them as `ScalaList` and `JavaList`.

Comment: @itisha minor note that, in general, the convention is to just import the **Java** one as `JList` and use the **Scala** one as just `List` _(i.e. without importing / renaming it)_. Of course, you are free to apply any renaming that make most sense for you and your team, just wanted to let you know that one I have seen used in other places.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the full qualified name of the list like:

`scala.collection.immutable.List`

or rename it when import like:

`import scala.collection.immutable.{List=> ScalaList}`